Ubuntu not shown in BIOS and as an option in the Boot menu
Pastebin link: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/x5H7XxQFXM/
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sdb and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdb: /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on nvme0n1p5
OS#2 (windows):   Windows 10 or 11 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GA102 [GeForce RTX 3080] from NVIDIA Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, noble, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 2.H7(5.17) from American Megatrends International, LLC.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0002,0000,0001
Boot0000* Ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,4961544f-c646-4e86-abc5-666d383a6df0,0x8800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0001* UEFI: PXE IPV4 Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x2)/Pci(0x0,0x2)/Pci(0x9,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(047c16083db7,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)0000424f
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,4961544f-c646-4e86-abc5-666d383a6df0,0x8800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000062360100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot0003* UEFI: Lexar USB Flash Drive 3.00, Partition 2 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x2)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/USB(3,0)/HD(2,GPT,1cf7d054-8db5-4194-971c-3c8665684807,0xb610ec,0x279c)0000424f

07e25dcaf57c776875f78fa36827c58e   nvme0n1p2/Boot/bootx64.efi
39bc76ff6662f4fbe9aa116e4c997b41   nvme0n1p2/Boot/fbx64.efi
4ba5a5aad43c197e9fb58b76b404d287   nvme0n1p2/Boot/mmx64.efi
66f69798ad23240e43b7ba0044a914c4   nvme0n1p2/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
4ba5a5aad43c197e9fb58b76b404d287   nvme0n1p2/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
07e25dcaf57c776875f78fa36827c58e   nvme0n1p2/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
13bbe79f47b4d57f791e51f5c01f7ac8   nvme0n1p2/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi
a7e895ae35e102411330a3e52636b457   nvme0n1p2/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
4c75682f8c4ddf9ca2f68ba84c3bf240   nvme0n1p2/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    34 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p5   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, fstab-has-bad-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
sda2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk identifier: 55C58A24-45C1-48C7-B5D0-E4A98C267BE4
      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
sda1      34     262177     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
sda2  264192 3907028991 3906764800  1.8T Microsoft basic data
Disk nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: 3F46BE2E-71BD-42ED-A427-5A34AD73024F
              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1       2048      34815      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p2      34816    1058815    1024000   500M EFI System
nvme0n1p3    1058816 1024438271 1023379456   488G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 1980014592 2000406527   20391936   9.7G Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p5 1024438272 1980014591  955576320 455.7G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sdb: 28.91 GiB, 31037849600 bytes, 60620800 sectors
Disk identifier: 1CF7D054-8DB5-4194-971E-3C8665684807
        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sdb1        64 11931883 11931820  5.7G Microsoft basic data
sdb2  11931884 11942023    10140    5M EFI System
sdb3  11942024 11942623      600  300K Microsoft basic data
sdb4  11943936 60618751 48674816 23.2G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:2000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA ST2000DM008-2FR1:;
1:17.4kB:134MB:134MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
2:135MB:2000GB:2000GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
sdb:31.0GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:Lexar USB Flash Drive:;
1:32.8kB:6109MB:6109MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:6109MB:6114MB:5192kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:6114MB:6115MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:6115MB:31.0GB:24.9GB:ext4::;
nvme0n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:INTEL SSDPEKNU010TZ:;
1:1049kB:17.8MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
2:17.8MB:542MB:524MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
3:542MB:525GB:524GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
5:525GB:1014GB:489GB:ext4::;
4:1014GB:1024GB:10.4GB:ntfs:Microsoft recovery partition:diag;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                  PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                   
├─sda1                                                    a1bc9919-2272-4c56-9f97-3bfaca38ce28                        Microsoft reserved partition
└─sda2      ntfs     B2368A123689D82D                     14931d5e-3fa7-45b4-89b4-672db4fdf4e0 Disk 0                 Basic data partition
sdb         iso9660  2024-04-24-11-29-09-00                                                    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS amd64 
├─sdb1      iso9660  2024-04-24-11-29-09-00               1cf7d054-8db5-4194-971f-3c8665684807 Ubuntu 24.04 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sdb2      vfat     37B6-BC6E                            1cf7d054-8db5-4194-971c-3c8665684807 ESP                    Appended2
├─sdb3                                                    1cf7d054-8db5-4194-971d-3c8665684807                        Gap1
└─sdb4      ext4     af5f304d-8bb9-4e7b-80fe-5fe50df91367 10e22b2b-c16e-4553-85bf-785e3e472126 writable               
nvme0n1                                                                                                               
├─nvme0n1p1                                               870bc7bb-33fb-476d-8413-8384f5a086cd                        Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p2 vfat     1E90-9DAF                            4961544f-c646-4e86-abc5-666d383a6df0 SYSTEM                 EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     C2069E08069DFD9B                     3f9de6e7-feae-4da7-9cc3-33087dd5ac08 Windows                Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     2014A5B914A59278                     41be5118-fabd-4695-9c1f-655e7cd62e21 Recovery               Microsoft recovery partition
└─nvme0n1p5 ext4     9d363429-24b9-40a6-9ac5-d409f0320150 4560ff24-7b95-4520-a374-c76cfd917bf5                        

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                               Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p2                                                464.3M   6% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2
/dev/nvme0n1p3                                                384.3G  21% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4                                                  1.2G  87% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p5                                                413.9G   2% /media/ubuntu/9d363429-24b9-40a6-9ac5-d409f0320150
/dev/sda2                                                       1.2T  32% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sdb1                                                          0 100% /cdrom
efivarfs                                                         76K  37% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p2                                                vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p3                                                fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p4                                                fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p5                                                ext4            rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sda2                                                     fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdb1                                                     iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8

=================== nvme0n1p2/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 9d363429-24b9-40a6-9ac5-d409f0320150 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p5/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   9d363429-24b9-40a6-9ac5-d409f0320150
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme0n1p2)   osprober-efi-1E90-9DAF
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p5/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/9d363429-24b9-40a6-9ac5-d409f0320150 / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/1E90-9DAF /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0

==================== nvme0n1p5/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

================= nvme0n1p5: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 772.874397278 = 829.867565056  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 577.605724335 = 620.199424000  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 577.605724335 = 620.199424000  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-49-generic                  1
 577.605724335 = 620.199424000  boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
 830.106082916 = 891.319619584  boot/initrd.img                                1
 529.136772156 = 568.156282880  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-31-generic               1
 830.106082916 = 891.319619584  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-49-generic               1
 830.106082916 = 891.319619584  boot/initrd.img.old                            1

=================== nvme0n1p5: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18133 Apr  4  2024 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43202 Apr  4  2024 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14513 Apr  4  2024 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Apr  4  2024 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13120 Apr  4  2024 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Apr  4  2024 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 Apr  5  2024 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr  4  2024 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr  4  2024 41_custom

mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3 
mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 


Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p5,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p2/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 24.04 LTS entry (nvme0n1p2/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)

I followed the install instructions on the official Ubuntu website and finished the installation.
Then I rebooted the PC, and it told me to remove the USB (just as the instruction said), and the PC quickly printed out several lines of error text, and then booted into Windows.
More details:

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Desktop 24.04.
I installed using a USB, as instructed here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#4-boot-from-usb-flash-drive
I used balenaEtcher to make the USB, as instructed. I did not change any settings in balenaEtcher (I don't even remember seeing any options.).
My PC has Windows 10 already installed, and both OSs are installed on an NVMe drive.


Looking at the grub boot order WIN appears before Ubuntu. So if you don't get a grub boot menu it will, by default, boot into WIN. Try to evoke the grub boot menu on boot by repeatable hitting ESC while booting and see if you get get the grub menu to show. You can change the boot order from Ubuntu but one step at a time.
